# .NET cmd multilinea

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, net

Buen dia lo que quiero es lo siguiente ,pasarle una serie de comandos a un cmd ,puedo inciar cmd y corro como ejemplo el siguiente codigo

```
 Dim comando, ip, punto As String
    punto = "."
    ip = TextBox1.Text + punto + TextBox2.Text + punto + TextBox3.Text + punto + TextBox4.Text
    comando = "ping " + ip
    Shell("cmd.exe /k" & comando)
```

Donde formo la ip y le hago un ping ,pero necesito que apenas termine lograr ingresar otra linea en esa misma ventana de cmd ,y finalmente se cierre esa ventana,hay alguna manera de hacerlo ,gracias

Comment: No creo que sea buena idea llamar al shell en una aplicacion asp.net. Por que no usas la clase [Ping](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) si es lo que necesitas?

Comment: lo que pasa es que tengo un .bat para instalar impresoras ,pero el codigo anteior solo me ejecuta una linea y el bat tiene muchas mas ,porque no he podido pasar una variable del .net al .bat en ejecucion